# Conditional Display on Item Value

Tags: oracle-apex

I have successfully created a form consisting of a couple of radio buttons and a drop-down select menu. I am trying to get the select menu to be visible only when a specific radio button is selected.

[image: Example Form]

For my situation, I would like the select menu to only be visible when the `No` radio button is selected.

The select menu is set as a child LOV item for the radio buttons, so when the radio buttons' value is changed the select menu's values are updated. However, what I have discovered is the conditional display conditions are not re-evaluated, which prevents the select menu being hidden or shown as the radio buttons are changed.

My initial solution was to set the radio button to redirect and set the value on change, but this ended up conflicting with logic elsewhere in my actual form (a lot more complicated than the example given).

The issue is definitely that cascading LOV parent items are not re-evaluating their child elements' conditional display options, so I was wondering if anyone has found a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **dynamic action** on change of the radio group.

Set the client side condition for the item to = 'N', there should be a declarative way to do this, but the JavaScript expression would be

```
$v('P1_RADIO') === 'N'
```

Add a true condition to Hide the select list item, and create an opposite action to Show it.

This implies >= APEX 4.x

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for :)